# Format string in SQL Server 2005 from numeric value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

How I can format string with `D` in start and leading zeros for digits with length of less than four. E.g:

- `D1000` for `1000`
- `D0100` for `100`

I have tried to work with casting and `stuff` function, but it didn't work as I expected.

```
SELECT STUFF('D0000', LEN(@OperatingEndProc) - 2, 4, CAST((CAST(SUBSTRING(@OperatingEndProc, 2, 4) AS INT) + 1) AS VARCHAR(10)));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

adding 10000 to the value will cause the number to have have extra zeros first, then casting it as varchar and only using the last 4 will ignore the added 10000. This require that all numbers are between 0 and 9999

```
declare @value int = 100

select 'D' + right(cast(@value + 10000 as varchar(5)), 4)
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Can you please provide some explanation?

Answer (score 0):

This illustration board can come in handy when you wanna get the proper casting practices..

> This shows all explicit and implicit data type conversions that are
>   allowed for SQL Server system-supplied data types. These include xml,
>   bigint, and sql_variant. There is no implicit conversion on assignment
>   from the sql_variant data type, but there is implicit conversion to
>   sql_variant

[image: The following illustration shows all explicit and implicit data type conversions that are allowed for SQL Server system-supplied data types. These include xml, bigint, and sql_variant. There is no implicit conversion on assignment from the sql_variant data type, but there is implicit conversion to sql_variant.]

You can download it here http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35834

Comment: How it touches my question?